# If $G$ and $H$ embed in each other and $Inn(G)\cong Inn(H)\cong Aut(H)\cong H$ does $G\cong H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group

I'm writing a pdf where I want to show that two groups $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic. To give some context, $G$ is the automorphism group of a commutative semi-ring $M$ and $H$ is the absolute Galois group of the rationals.
I can prove that $G$ and $H$ embed in each other, and that $Inn(G)\cong Inn(H)$, the latter being isomorphic to $Aut(H)$ and to $H$ itself.

Can I conclude that $G\cong H$?

Comment: Using “pdf” for “paper”. Neat.

Comment: Are the isomorphisms abstract or are they canonical and induced by the mentioned embeddings?

Comment: They are abstract.

Comment: Do you know a reference for $Aut(H) = H?$ in your context?

Comment: Yes, see corollary 12.2.3 in Cohomology of number fields by Neukirch et al.

Comment: Could a software like GAP help answer this question?